# How to get days dd in dd/mm/yyyy in a dateime column

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I want to get all the `dd` in `dd/mm/yyyy` date column. How do I write the query for it? 
For Example: If I want `dd` between `28/06/2011` to `02/07/2011`, then I should get the output like this:

```
28
29
30
01
02
```

Please help me through this

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using a tally table

```
DECLARE @StartDate date = '2011-06-28'
DECLARE @EndDate date = '2011-07-02'

SELECT right(convert(varchar, dateadd(day,number,@Startdate), 111), 2)
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE type = 'P' AND number BETWEEN 0 AND DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate)
```

You should be aware that this is limited to 2047 days. If you need more than that, you should consider recusive.

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @FromDate date = '20110628';
declare @ToDate date = '20110702';

with cte(TheDate) as
(
  select @FromDate
  union all
  select dateadd(d, 1, TheDate)
  from cte       
  where TheDate < @ToDate
)
select right('0'+cast(datepart(day, TheDate) as varchar(2)), 2) as TheDay
from cte
order by TheDate;
```

Comment: Alternatively: `… RIGHT(100 + DATEPART(…), 2) …`.

Comment: @AndriyM I didnt realize you could use right on a number, I just experiemented with it, very cool

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: Ultimately `RIGHT` is applied to a string, of course, to which the number is converted implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

my friend here are a sql server function that can help you :

```
select datepart (dw, '5/11/7') as dayOfTheWeek,
       datename (dw, '5/11/7') as NameOfDay
```

that is for one date then you can make for loop on each date and store the result in data table

mark as answered if it helps :)

Comment: You need tally table or recusive for this. Not a loop. Loops in sql is rarely a good solution

Answer (score 0):

Use `DATEPART(dd, dateColumnName)`

`DATEPART(dd, '28/06/2011')` returns `28`

More details on [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I have something like that. you can use or create as many day period you can adding `CROSS JOIN` in CTE.

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY

DECLARE @d1 datetime, @d2 datetime

SET @d1 = '28/06/2011'
SET @d2 = '02/07/2011';

WITH LIST(E) AS (
SELECT 1 E UNION ALL SELECT 2 E UNION ALL SELECT 3 E UNION ALL SELECT 3 E UNION ALL 
SELECT 4 E UNION ALL SELECT 6 E UNION ALL SELECT 6 E UNION ALL SELECT 7 E UNION ALL 
SELECT 8 E UNION ALL SELECT 9 E UNION ALL SELECT 10 E UNION ALL SELECT 12 E UNION ALL 
SELECT 12 E 
),

Numbers (number) AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY L.E) Number FROM LIST L --CROSS JOIN LIST J
)

SELECT DATEPART(D,DATEADD(D,N.NUMBER-1,@D1)) FROM Numbers n WHERE DATEADD(D,N.NUMBER-1,@D1) <= @D2
```